# Do we need choice to prove that $|\mathbb{N} \times A| = |A|$ for all infinite sets $A$?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice

I can't think of any way to prove it without choice.

Comment: Yes. For example, it is consistent without choice that there are infinite Dedekind finite sets, that is, infinite sets into which $\mathbb N$ does not inject.

Comment: What ways have you tried to prove it? This question doesn't show any motivation (where did you encounter the problem?), and it doesn't show what your own attempts have been (what sort of proof are you looking for?)

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You need the axiom of choice. To see this note that we can prove the following (without the axiom of choice):

$$|A\times\Bbb N|=|A|\iff |A\times\{0,1\}|=|A|.$$

So it suffices to show that it is consistent that the latter fails. For this we can have many nice counterexamples. My favorites are $\kappa$-amorphous sets.

> **Definition.** We say that $A$ is $\kappa$-amorphous, for an ordinal $\kappa$ if $|A|\nleq\kappa$, and for every $B\subseteq A$ either $|B|<\kappa$ or $|A\setminus B|<\kappa$.

Clearly if such set exists then $|A|<|A\times\{0,1\}|$ since the latter can be split into two sets neither of which is smaller than $\kappa$ in size. And such sets consistently exist.

Comment: I hope that whoever downvoted will help me improve this post using verbal feedback as well.